# How do I represent an un-normalized table in an XML format?

Tags: xml, normalization

I currently have this table:

[image]

I attempted to carry out the task and got this far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VideoRental>

    <Video copyNumber="2">
        <Videotitle>The Sting</Videotitle>
        <Artist>Redford</Artist>
        <Length>135</Length>
    </video>

    <Borrower cardNumber="145">
        <Name>Jim Jones</Name>
    </Borrower>

</VideoRental>
```

I do not know if what I have done is correct or not. I was unable to represent the `dateDue` and `daysOverdue` attribute because I could not find a way to represent them in the XML I created.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  [Representing a date in XML](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp).  The normalization state of a table doesn't have anything to do with writing an XML representation; you write the XML the same way you would for any other data.  Don't ask for tutorials; that's what Google is for.  Capitalize your I's.

Comment: No programming language, I just want to create a basic text file containing the XML to represent the data from the table presented.

Comment: So the only thing that you're missing is how to represent dates?

Comment: Yes, but I also want to know if the structure I used (as shown in the XML above) is correct or not, or whether there is a better way to represent the un-normalized data in a different XML structure.

Comment: How do you define "better?"

Comment: I there another structure that I could have used to represent the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would express borrower and date due with following record in your xml:

```
<Rental Borrower="145" DateDue="2/29/06" videoId="2" copyNumber="1" />
```

And copies expressed like this (I would suggest to remove copyNumber from video, or you would have to copy-paste titles and artist for multiple copies of the same video):

```
<Copies>
  <Copy videoId="2" copyNumber="1"/>
  <Copy videoId="2" copyNumber="2"/>
  <Copy videoId="3" copyNumber="1"/>
</Copies>
```

Days overdue is clearly a computed property, always changing, and should not be stored.
Also, I think you should put all Video, Person, and Rental tags into parent tags like this:

```
<Persons>
  <Person ... />
  <Person ... />
</Persons>
<Rentals>
  <Rental ... />
  <Rental ... />
</Rentals>
```

etc

Comment: CopyNumber represents the copy of the video so that the shop can uniquely identify it.

Comment: So record means 'copy 5 of star wars is not borrowed by anyone'. Ok, probably it is another entity here. Does list represent all copies? Can there be multiple star wars, with no borrower, but different copy number?